# VBScript get custom object from array

Tags: arrays, vbscript

I have some problems with an array in VBScript: I have a central array, in this I save some custom objects. Later on, I want access these elements to print out the objects. But this don't work.
Here is my code;

```
sub start
    redim selektionsArray(0)
    for i = 0 to 10
            Dim TheDude : Set TheDude = (New Selektion2)("a" & i, "b" & i)

            ReDim Preserve selektionsArray(ubound(selektionsArray) + 1)
            set selektionsArray(ubound(selektionsArray)) = TheDude
            'Works
            msgbox selektionsArray(ubound(selektionsArray)).Typ & " = " & selektionsArray(ubound(selektionsArray)).Wert
    next 

    dim i
    for i = 0 to ubound(selektionsArray)
        set element3 = selektionsArray(i)
        'don't work
        msgbox selektionsArray(i).Typ & " = " & selektionsArray(i).Wert
    next

    dim sel
    for each sel in selektionsArray
        'don't work to
        msgbox sel.Wert
    next

    'strange thing is ubound(selektionsArray) --> 11

end sub

Class Selektion2
     Private m_typ
     Private m_wert

     Public Default Function Init(Typ, Wert)
         m_typ = Typ
         m_wert = Wert

         Set Init = Me
     End Function

     Public Property Get Typ 
         Typ = m_typ
     End Property

     Public Property Get Wert
         Wert = m_wert
     End Property

     public function getWert()
        getWert = m_wert
     end function
 End Class
```

I don't can access the array-Elements outside the initialisation loop, what is here wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is to assume that

```
redim selektionsArray(0)
```

creates an empty array. It does not, the array has an empty first element at index 0. Adding further objects is no problem, but when you try to

```
set element3 = selektionsArray(i)
```

for i = 0, or to access the firs sel in the For Each loop, that empty element can't be use to Set the/a variable. So change the 'create my array' statement to

```
redim selektionsArray(-1)
```